# Help connecting MSE and residual variance $(=σ^2/(1-h_{ii}$)) in linear regression

Tags: regression, residuals, leverage

In linear regression, we assume errors are normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $σ^2$.

We use MSE = (Residual sum of squares) / (n-p) as the estimator for σ, where n= number of observations and p = number of coefficients.

I think I understand the concept till here. However, when we come to standardized residuals, we say that the residuals are not a good estimator for the error variance, and calculate the variance of residuals as

var[$r_i$] = $σ^2(1 − h_{ii})$ where $h_{ii}$ is the relevant entry from the hat matrix

Therefore, $σ^2 = var[r_i]/(1-h_{ii})$

I am not able to reconcile this with the MSE formula. I believe this has some connection with adding all variances, and the trace of the hat matrix being equal to p, but I am not yet able to draw the connection clearly.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552311/unbiasedness-of-covariance-matrix-estimator-in-ols/552418#552418